# How to set event-loop pool size in Spring Webflux / WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-webflux

In **multi-reactor** framework such as Vert.X we can set the number of event-loop threads, e.g.:

```
final VertxOptions vertxOptions = new VertxOptions();
vertxOptions.setEventLoopPoolSize(16);
final Vertx myVertx = Vertx.vertx(vertxOptions);
```

How to do the equivalent in Spring Boot 2 WebFlux / WebClient?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Override `ReactiveWebServerFactory` bean with a customizer that applies event loop resources config:

   ```
   @Bean
   public ReactiveWebServerFactory reactiveWebServerFactory() {
       NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory = new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory();
       factory.addServerCustomizers(builder -> builder.loopResources(LoopResources.create("my-http", 16, true)));

       return factory;
   }
   ```
2. Or use `-Dreactor.ipc.netty.workerCount=16` environment variable. By default it's value is set to `Math.max(availableProcessors(), 4)`. 
   Example: `java -jar your-app.jar -Dreactor.ipc.netty.workerCount=16`

Comment: reactor.ipc.netty.workerCount does not work in application.properties file.

Comment: @SaeedZarinfam and it shouldn't as it's an Environment variable, not property. Updated the answer to be more precise.

Comment: I'm getting builder.loopResources is not defined.

Comment: how do i verify the settings are applied correctly? Is there a simple way to print out the number of workerCount?

Comment: hi just wondering does the name of method "resourceFactory()" matter? Can i use a different name to achieve the same thing?

Comment: This is now renamed to "reactor.netty.ioWorkerCount".

Answer (score 2):

The event loop is implemented by the Spring project reactor, all requests are processed by the event-loop, internally it uses reactive Netty to handle the web requests. In Boot 2.XX uses Reactor Netty 0.8 or higher version, the equivalent system property is named as reactor.netty.ioWorkerCount. which is documented as "Default worker thread count"

you can define event-loop pool size by adding this

VM argument **-Dreactor.netty.ioWorkerCount=2**

Example: java -jar your-app.jar -Dreactor.netty.ioWorkerCount=2