# Throughput in spring boot netty web application

Tags: java, spring, netty, throughput, high-load

I would like to improve throughput in my web-server. 
But I don't understand what is really happening when I am testing it with high load (jmeter).

I run spring boot `webflux` app (`spring boot 2.0.2, netty`) on a computer with `8 core` cpu.
I created a simple controller with this code:

```
@GetMapping("/test-delay")
public Mono<String> testGetWithDelay() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    return Mono.just("current time:" + LocalDateTime.now());
}
```

`"Thread.sleep(3000)"` - it is an imitation of synchronous works. 
Then I run `jmeter tests` with 100 threads. And I see a throughput only `2.5 message/sec`. I thought it should be about 100 `messages/3 sec` (about 30 messages/sec)

So, I have 2 questions:

1. why the throughput so low
2. how can I manage it

Thanks

Comment: Why should it? You have a blocking operation in a non-blocking service, next to that you can handle at most 8 concurrent tasks (actually it depends on your CPU architecture) and if all of them are waiting nothing will happen for some time. also generally when using an reactive approach you won't get better performance but better resource utilization meaning you can do the same with less resources as with blocking operations.

Comment: Thanks, @M.Deinum Please, could you give me an advice, how can I improve throughput in my case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your results are correct. You get 2.5 message/sec with delay 3 secs (in every thread), that gives us `2.5 * 3 = 7.5 = 8` cores. Webflux by default uses `availableProcessors()` as a default number of threads for processing network/work IO.

So what you need to do is either [increase the number of processing threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48736669/7110799) or move `Thread.sleep(3000)` block to separate `ThreadPool/Executor` (so working threads are not blocked) or your `Thread.sleep(3000)` code should be executed in some kind of non-blocking API (for example in webflux you may use `Mono.fromCallable`).

I would recommend you to go with the second/third approach, as non-blocking API should never be blocked.

Comment: Would `mono.delayElement` not also achieve the same result?

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys ! I hope, I understood the main idea. I will try to use it