# How to increase worker threads of reactor WebClient?

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-reactor

I am using Spring reactor Webflux 2.3.1

I am using a webClient to make some http calls.

**(org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient)**

How can I increase the number of worker threads, IO threads and maybe the number of event loops?

Comment: this is a server specific question and the answer is different depending on what underlying implementation that is used, netty, undertow, tomcat, jetty. You can probably find how to tweak your specific server in each servers documentation.

Answer (score 1):

check https://stackoverflow.com/a/48736669/10059236
But increasing pool size doesn't make much sense, because all network I/O is non-blocking anyway